# Is LinkingObjects just using RealmList?

Tags: android, realm

I want to create **LinkingObjects** with **VolleyballPlayer** table inside the **Player** table. In the examples on the internet, I have always seen the use of `RealmList<VolleyballPlayer>`.

Is there a usage like the one below, with only **VolleyballPlayer** in the **Player**?

Another question I have is: It is written that **LinkingObjects** migration is not required, but I saw that old records are not coming in this use. How can I fetch my old records without migration?

```
public class Player extends RealmObject {
private VolleyballPlayer volleyballPlayer;
}

public class VolleyballPlayer extends RealmObject {

    @LinkingObjects("volleyballPlayer")
    private final RealmResults<Player> playerList = null;
}
```

Comment: For clarity, Realm does not have tables - it an *object* database, not an *SQL* database. In general, a Parent object would have a List of child objects. Those child objects have a backlinks property that's essentially a computed property which points back the parent. e.g. When a child is added to a parent, the child's backlinks property is auto-populated. If you want to navigate the graph from a VolleyballPlayer to a Player, you could use a backlink [Inverse Relationship](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/kotlin/realm-database/schemas/relationships/#inverse-relationships)

Comment: Oh - one thing about posting here on SO. Please keep questions to one question per post. Having multiple questions can make answers confusing and very long and will likely lead to the question being closed as "Needs More Focus: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only."